# How to connect Laravel website with mongoDB atlas

Tags: json, laravel, mongodb, httprequest, cluster-computing

I try to connect my laravel website with Mondo DB atlas cluster. Previously I connect this database with mysql database.   But I go an error

my code on config/database.php

```
'mongodb_conn' => [
    'driver' => 'mongodb',
    'dsn'=>'mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@mydbname-ktp6o.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    'database' => 'mydbname',
],
```

And my code in .env

```
    APP_NAME=Blood_Donation
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:jtvoXduyfwnIB6A5pCy8Cfa9bJYRvNgMKeRFdfiYYyc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mongodb_conn'
DB_HOST=xxxx-shard-00-00-uggj0.mongodb.net
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=mydbname
DB_USERNAME=myusername
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

I got below error when I run PHP artisan serve.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyD5y.jpg)

Comment: I remove it. API is lunguage indipendent

Comment: Laravel has documentation. I suggest reading it. https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers

Answer (score 4):

If you are using XAMPP for Localhost(Apache Server) and MongoDB Atlas as the Database you should refer this [**Jenssegers**](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb).

```
$ composer require jenssegers/mongodb
```

and make sure to install **MongoDB extension to XAMPP** [**XAMPP + MongoDB Configuration**](https://learnedia.com/install-mongodb-configure-php-xampp-windows/)(Do Until Step 4)

### .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=xxxx-shard-00-00-uggj0.mongodb.net
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE={your_database}
DB_USERNAME={username_when_creating_cluster}
DB_PASSWORD={password_when_creating_cluster}
```

### config/database.php

```
   'mongodb' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'dsn' => 'mongodb+srv://{username_when_creating_cluster}:{password_when_creating_cluster}@{your_cluster_name}.bhtvj.gcp.mongodb.net/{your_database}?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
            'database' => '{your_database}',
        ],
```

Please note that above **dsn** can easily get from [MongoDB|Atlas](https://cloud.mongodb.com/) and you should only edit credential for the cluster and the database name.

### Step 1

[image: Step 1]

### Step 2

[image: Step 2]

### Step 3

[image: Step 3]

Hope this is the answer you looking for Goodluck!

Answer (score -3):

I don't know what you really want in this question, but to send a request, you can use 
HTML  tags or AJAX